# Pull names of variables with a threshold of missing values

Tags: r, function, missing-data

I am working with a data set containing 93 columns and many of them have a large percentage of missing values. I am looking for a way to streamline screening each column for the percentage of missing values and then return a list of names of those variables above that threshold to include in a new data set.

I have a function to check for missing values and return the percentage of missing:

```
#check for missing data
pMiss <- function(x) {
  sum(is.na(x))/length(x)*100
}

#percent of data missing per column
x <- apply(dt2,2,pMiss)
```

How can I retrieve all the names [from x] of the columns where the percent of missing values is less than 20%? I would like to retrieve these names as a list that I can paste into a new data set, so I don't have to manually copy and paste each name from x.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll work:

```
# example dataset
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(c(1,2,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE), 
                  b=sample(c(1,2,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE), 
                  c=sample(c(1:10,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE))

threshold <- .25 # for example

# get subset of colnames s.t. NA proportion is greater than threshold
names(dat)[sapply(dat, function(x) mean(is.na(x)) > threshold)]
## [1] "a" "b"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(NA,NA,1,1),b=c(NA,1,1,1),c=c(1,1,1,1))
x <- colMeans(is.na(df))
# a    b    c 
# 0.50 0.25 0.00

x[x < .3]
# b    c 
# 0.25 0.00

names(x[x < .3])
# [1] "b" "c"
```

or all in one line:

```
names(df)[colMeans(is.na(df)) < .3]
# [1] "b" "c"
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tidyverse` approach:

```
require(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(c(1,2,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE), 
                  b=sample(c(1,2,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE), 
                  c=sample(c(1:10,NA), size=20, replace=TRUE))

threshold <- .43 

dat %>% 
  gather(var, value) %>% 
  group_by(var) %>% 
  summarise(prep.missing = sum(is.na(value)) / n()) %>% 
  filter(prep.missing < threshold)

  var   prep.missing
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 a            0.400
2 c            0.
```

Comment: Thank you! Extremely helpful